# How to solve "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'file'" once and for all in python webapp2 at file upload?

Tags: python, file-upload, webapp2

I already saw similar questions here describing same problem, peoples gives there answers and someones even respond it helped, but nothing from it totally works for me.

This is my code:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action = "/anomalydetector" enctype = "multipart-form-data" method = "post">
      File: <input name = "attachment" type = "file" /><br />
      Analyzer sensitivity in percents: <input type = "text" name = "sensitivity" value = "10" /><br />
      <input type = "submit" value = "Analyze" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the handler:

```python
class AnomalyDetectorPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        uploaded_file = self.request.POST.get("attachment");
        file_data = uploaded_file.file.read();
```

I always getting error of this kind:

```pytb
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test-ml/1.398533980585659886/main.py", line 207, in post
    file_data = uploaded_file.file.read();
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'file'
```

I understand that python thinks that files are strings, but what I can do with it???

I tried `self.request.POST.get("attachment").file.read()`, `self.request.POST["attachment"].file.read()`, `self.request.get("attachment").file.read()` and `self.request.POST.multi["attachment"].file.read()` and maybe something else, but I always getting this error.

What I can do to read content of this file?

Comment: According to the error message `uploaded_file` is a Unicode object. What does it look like when you print it?

Comment: @PM2Ring - like a file name that were put into field. Just filename, without path.

Comment: @Kosmos why do you expect a file name to have a `file` attribute?

Comment: @Goyo - I expect it to be not a filename, but a `cgi.FieldStorage` object

Comment: @Kosmos silly question, I misread the previous comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `enctype` attribute value you are using is wrong. The form should be sent over:

```
multipart/form-data
```

---

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/anomalydetector" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    File: <input name="attachment" type="file" />
    <br />
    Analyzer sensitivity in percents: <input type="text" name="sensitivity" value="10" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Analyze" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh... looks like I copied it wrongly from somewhere and... you see the result. Thanks!